# Phoenix Framework : Enum.map while using with statement. Is it possible?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I want to get a result from the function using `with` statement. But what I want is exactly this;

For each row, I have to validate the `role` column and proceed, if a column is invalid I want the function to exit from `with` statement and give an output as `:error`.

The code below not working but is it possible to do something similar like this?

```
def get_validation_result(rows) do

    with {:ok, "valid"} <- rows
    |> Enum.map(fn row ->
      role = get_role(row)
      validate_role(role)
    end) do
      {:ok, "valid"}
    else
      {:error, error} ->
      IO.puts :stdio, "invalid"
    end

end
```

Comment: There are some common idioms in Elixir:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is [`Enum.reduce_while/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#reduce_while/3) which can traverse the enumerable and stop at a certain point.

On the other hand, `with` can group pattern matching when you're writing the code but has no dynamic ability.

```
def validate(rows) do
  Enum.reduce_while(rows, :ok, fn row, _ ->
    case get_role(row) |> validate_role() do
      :ok -> {:cont, :ok}
      other -> {:halt, other}
    end
  end)
end
```

Comment: It is very helpful answer, thank you qhwa.